# ThreeJS post processing, blending effect composer passes

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I'm trying to figure how to use the EffectComposer in ThreeJS.

Trying to apply motion blur to a mesh while keeping the background mesh sharp.

The only way I sort of was able to get it to work was by losing depth with the background overlapping the front elements:

http://code.michael-iriarte.com/post-process-test/test-1.html

But I'd like to be able to render something more like that (but with the motion blur):

http://code.michael-iriarte.com/post-process-test/test-2.html

See two examples below:

[image: test 1 and 2]

```
composerBack.addPass( renderBack );

composerFront.addPass( renderFront );
composerFront.addPass( renderMaskInverseFront );
composerFront.addPass( effectHBlur );
composerFront.addPass( effectVBlur );
composerFront.addPass( clearMask );

composerMerge.addPass( rttPassBack );                    
// composerMerge.addPass( renderMaskInverseBack );
composerMerge.addPass( renderMaskFront );
composerMerge.addPass( rttPassFront );
composerMerge.addPass( clearMask );

composerMerge.addPass( effectCopy);
```

Some help on the topic would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a bit weird talking to myself on Stackoverflow :)

All I was missing was:

```
rttPassFront = new THREE.TexturePass( composerFront.renderTarget2.texture );   
rttPassFront.material.transparent = true;
```

See a demo here:

http://code.michael-iriarte.com/post-process-test/solution-1.html

I hope it helps others. If you have different approach, please share!!

Comment: i wish your link wasn't broken :<

Comment: @ThomasChapman there is a very similar example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/webgl.michael-iriarte.com/post-processors/pretty-cube.html and https://s3.amazonaws.com/webgl.michael-iriarte.com/post-processors/pretty-cube-2.html